# Part of the mesh is flat and the other is smooth

Tags: mesh, smooth

I have a mesh which there is a section which is not smooth, but in edited mode I can see it is smooth. (although I have chosen the shade smooth option). I have used used a modifier data transfer, don't know if this is the reason which causes this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file

Comment: Here it is thanks: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=WqvRrZAY" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/WqvRrZAY/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redo the topology, first remove this part, then select the opposite edges:

[image]

And <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> > *Grid Fill*:

[image]

Extend the bar into the big one

[image]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> > *Intersect (Boolean)* and in the *Operator* box choose the *Union* mode:

[image]

Here is the result:

[image]

You'll have to correct the topology, enable the *Auto Merge* option and the *Snap (to Vertex)* in order to merge vertices, also dissolve some edges:

[image]

Result with the *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]